# Error when adding Xamarin Text Field to Layout

Tags: android, layout, crash, xamarin

I am trying to add a text field (drag and drop) to an android layout through the layout designer, but I get the error in the image below, this happens in Xamarin studio.

If I try doing the same steps in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, it crashes the visual studio!

[image]

any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Java SE bug.  You need to make sure you have valid Java Environment.

I would recommend, you uninstall Java kit and and reinstall it.
When you do that, make sure Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio are not open.

This actually is a known bug but it gets solved by updating/reinstalling Java Environment.

Also, if you have Xamarin Studio updates, you should install them as well.

[Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12649)